# Integrating for velocity

Tags: integration

Trying to determine velocity of a falling body with respect to traveled distance and initial speed. I've been provided with the following equation for acceleration as a function of distance and the grav. parameter(constant) of the attracting body :

$a= GM/r^2$

Where:

a - acceleration.
GM - gravitational parameter(constant).
r - distance to the attracting body.

I have entered inputs for GM and r and integrated this equation with respect to $r$. This obviously yielded total acceleration per traveled distance, in other words $m^2/s^2$ at the given altitude.

How do I proceed to determine velocity at this altitude?

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the general strategy for a problem of this kind. You know that acceleration is the instantaneous rate of change of position:
$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}$$
Through change of variables, this can also be equal to:
$$a=\frac{dv}{dx}\times\frac{dx}{dt}.$$
By chain rule:
$$a=v\frac{dv}{dx}$$

Knowing the acceleration as a function of position means you have:
$$v\frac{dv}{dx}=a(x) \implies v\cdot dv = a(x)dx $$

Integrating both sides simply gives you velocity as a function of position. Punch in your acceleration due to gravity and the integral is trivial.

Comment: Just pointing out the physics. This elimination of time as an independent variable is precisely what energy conservation means. You circumvent all this hassle if you simply start with energy conservation:

$$\frac{mv^2}{2}-\frac{mGM}{r}={\rm const}$$

Comment: In this case that is correct. But, only because gravity is a conservative force. In my opinion, the mathematical approach is more appropriate here as it always works, and this is also mathematics stackexchange, not physics.

Comment: Sure, but if it's not a conservative force, you can't do the transformation that you did. I'm just pointing out that the transformation $dv/dx\cdot dx/dt$ leads you diretly to energy conservation. Giving perspective. You can ignore it if you wish.